# Same code but different output of 'this' for VS Code and browser console

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I have executed the following code both in VS Code and browser console

```js
var message = 'I am your teacher'

function executeWorkshop(greeting){
  return function ask(){
    console.log(`${greeting}, ${this.message}`);
  }
}

executeWorkshop("Hi")();
```

**Outputs**

**VS Code:**

```
Hi, undefined
```

**Browser:**

```
Hi, I am your teacher
```

Comment: That's because in browser this is translated to window and you don't have it in node environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For web browsers, we have a **window** object. It provides the browser window functionality and also plays the role of a global object. When scripts create global variables in the web browsers, they're created as members of the global object(window object).

In Node.js, This is not the case. NodeJs has something called **global** object.

Here are some facts:

- In the Node.js module system, each file is treated as a separate
  module.
- The Global objects are available in all modules.
- While in browsers, the global scope is the window object, in nodeJS,
  the global scope of a module is the module itself, so when you define a variable in the global scope of your Node.js module, it will be local to this module.

NodeJs:
[image: On NodeJs]

Browser:
[image: On Browser]